# Why cannot I grab items from api/context?(react question)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a simple react app for lending phones with this [api](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/warp/etn-device-checker-test/1.0#/default/post_login).

I am trying to grab the mobiles with context api like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext
 
} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export const MobileContext = createContext({
 mobiles: [],
  setMobiles: () => {},
  updateMobiles: () => {},
});

export default function MobileProvider(props) {
  const [mobiles, setMobiles] = useState([]);
  
  const updateMobiles = (id) => {
 
    axios
      .get('https://js-test-api.etnetera.cz/api/v1/phones')
      .then((res) => setMobiles(res.data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://js-test-api.etnetera.cz/api/v1/phones')
      .then((res) => setMobiles(res.data));
      
  }, [] );

  return (
    <MobileContext.Provider value={{ mobiles, setMobiles, updateMobiles }}>
      {props.children}
    </MobileContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and reuse them at the main page after logging in

```
import React from 'react'
import { MobileContext } from './MobileContext';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Mobile from './Mobile';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
function MobileList() {
    const { mobiles } = useContext(MobileContext);
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
         {mobiles.map((item) => (
          <Mobile
           vendor={item.vendor} 
           
          />
        ))}  
        
       
        </div>
    )
}

export default MobileList
```

and this is the single mobile component

```
import React from 'react'

function Mobile(props) {
    return (
        <div>
       <p>{props.vendor}</p>    
    <p> ssssssssssss</p> 
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default Mobile
```

after the correct logging in, it should display both the text and the vendor for each mobile but it isnt displaying anything besides the navbar [image: this is how it looks]
this would probably mean, that I am not getting the mobiles from the api in the first place, but I am not sure why is that. The auth token could also be the reason why I am not able to access the phones,never used it before.
Anyway, this is the [full code](https://github.com/JanLinhart/etnetera) and I would apreciate any help

login.js

```
   import React from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
    function Login() {
        const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
        const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
        
       
        let history = useHistory()
        const onSubmit = (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const getIn = {
          
            "login":email,
            "password":password,
            
        
          };
      
          
          axios
            .post('https://js-test-api.etnetera.cz/api/v1/login', getIn,
            {
                headers: {
                    
                     'content-type': 'application/json', 
               }
            }).then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data); 
          history.push("/phones");
        })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
           
        };
        return (
            <div>
               <form >
             <label>email</label> <input value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="text"/>
            <label>password</label>  <input type="text" value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <button onClick={onSubmit}>login</button>
               </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's the get api expecting an auth token. You need to first login using the login endpoint and get the token from the login response. Post that you can pass that auth token in each get request in the header.

You can update your context file like so :-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext
 
} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export const MobileContext = createContext({
 login:()=>{},
 mobiles: [],
  setMobiles: () => {},
  updateMobiles: () => {},
});

export default function MobileProvider(props) {
  const [mobiles, setMobiles] = useState([]);
  const [token,setToken] = useState(null);
  
  const login = (username,password) =>{
    // do the axios post thing - take ref from docs you shared for request body
    // get the token from the response and you can set it in the state
      setToken(token);
   }
  
  const updateMobiles = (id) => {
    //Update this get request with proper header value using token state as well.
    axios
      .get('https://js-test-api.etnetera.cz/api/v1/phones')
      .then((res) => setMobiles(res.data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
     //Update this get request with proper header value using token state as well.
    axios
      .get('https://js-test-api.etnetera.cz/api/v1/phones')
      .then((res) => setMobiles(res.data));
      
  }, [] );

  return (
    <MobileContext.Provider value={{ login,mobiles, setMobiles, updateMobiles }}>
      {props.children}
    </MobileContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Note - How you wan't to use that login function is upto you but generally its through form submission. In your case I think it's an auto login inside an `useEffect`, so don't hardcode username and password in the UI. You can use environment variables for the same.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention it, but I already have a seperate file login.js where I am posting it. I mean having the login component in the context file would make no sense right?, because its just another page. Anyway I added the login.js at the end of the question

Comment: Don't have login component in context file but the login logic should be in the context as I did it. This would allow you to get token at any route considering your MobileProvider will at the top level. And now you can make that token part of the context value and use it in any component to make any request (I haven't made token as part of context value but I hope you get the idea)

Comment: Well thanks so much but I have two questions...how should I really get the token and how do I reuse it? I mean in headers oor?

Comment: How should I really get the token ? - Once you make the post request to login endpoint, the response will give you an object where one of the keys will be token. Store that token inside a state in MobileProvider.

How to reuse it ? - Your token should be maintained in a state inside your MobileProvider. That state is usable by axios.get right ? Just make a header object and pass in the header key and token state value as required by docs.